# Test offline browsing with Android Chrome

Tags: offline-caching, service-worker, offline-mode

I am trying to build an offline-data persistent web application with Service Workers. I managed to have it working on my laptop Chrome (51) and it loads the cached files and displays an offline message when I simulate being offline via the Chrome DevTools - Network tab.
I uploaded the application to github to make sure it is available with https (https://mguardos.github.io/index.html)

However, when I try to test it with my Android Chrome (Nexus 5 - Android 6.0.1 - Chrome 51), the application loads fine when online, but if I set the plane mode on and reload the page, the browsers is not checking the service worker but displaying the offline message directly

"You are offline.
Your devide is offline.
Try: ...
ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"

Is there any option that I have to enabled in my Android Chrome for Service workers to work?

Thanks for any tip

PS (edited): Same issue occurs with Opera 37 on Android 6.0.1. However, the Registration service happens properly for both Chrome and Opera in the background (validated via an alert upon the registration method is successfully completed)

PSS: The link above tries to be a very basic example of combining service workers with AppCache, to retrieve localStorage and IndexedDB data so any constructive critic would be very much appreciated on top of the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in Chrome seems to be that it requires the entry **'/'** to be added to the files to be cached for the Service Worker. I added that entry and I could see the application working fine while offline with my Android

However, the problem with Opera remains the same, I can even replicate it with the https://airhorner.com app

- Just Open Opera (make sure you clean the cache before)
- go to https://airhorner.com (the application loads fine - although it does not sound)
- Activate airplane mode
- Reload the page (the application still loads because it is reading from local cache)
- Close the browser or simply go to a different address
- Then go back to https://airhorner.com (The Offline message I added to the original question appears)

I will continue my investigation and will potential create a new question just for the Opera browser, as this question has been answered for Chrome